# Show $|\langle x\rangle|=|\langle x^2\rangle|$ if the order of $x$ is odd.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $x$ be an element of odd finite order of a group $G$.  Show that $x^2$ has the same order as $x$.

What I did was since $x^{2n+1}=e$ for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.  We get that $(x^2)^{2n+1}=(x^{2n+1})^2=e^2=e$.  However how can I be sure that this is the smallest $n$ for which $x^{4n+2}=e$ ?

Comment: Hint: If $x^m=e$ then $ |\langle x\rangle|$ divides $m$.

Comment: $o(x^m) = \frac{o(x)}{\gcd(o(x),m)}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $|x^2|=m$. Then from the exact same argument of @Magdiragdag i.e:

$({x^2})^{m}=e \Rightarrow x^{2m}=e$. But order of $x$ is $2n+1$. Hence $2n+1|2m$. Note that $2m$ is even and $2n+1$ is odd. Hence $2n+1|m$.

Now coming to your argument, you showed that $(x^2)^{2n+1}=e.$ But order of $x^2$ is $m$, hence $m|2n+1$.

So we have that $2n+1|m$ and $m|2n+1$. Which implies $m=2n+1$.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $m > 0$ is such that $(x^2)^{m} = e$, i.e., $x ^ {2m} = e$. By Langrange, $\text{ord}(x) \mid 2m$, i.e., $2 n + 1 \mid 2m$ and therefore $2 n + 1 \mid m$. So, $m \geq 2n + 1$.

Comment: I can see the argument, but wouldn't this work when the order isn't odd as well, in general is this true always.  Or is there something i'm missing about it being odd that makes it true only in this case.

Comment: The step from $2n + 1 | 2m$ to $2n + 1 | m$ uses the fact that $2n + 1$ is odd.